# How to preserve old range of values clipping multi-band raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, multi-band

Old raster:

[image]

New one after use of "clipper" or GDAL clipping:

[image]

Is it any other (faster) method than "save/load style" to preserve previous values of raster? I'm running QGIS 2.14.